# Preventing lock screen in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How to prevent the lock screen from being activated if the screen isn't touched? I've tried with:

```
the_screenmanager.on_pause=False
```

but it didn't work. Thanks in advance for ideas!

Comment: what kind of os?

Comment: @PalimPalim The app is for android.

Comment: If you are using `buildozer` to build your app, you can add the `WAKE_LOCK` permission to your list of `android.permissions` in your `buildozer.spec` file, and add the `android.wakelock = True` line to the same spec file.